# Adapting Neural Network to new domain without labels

Tags: neural-network, semi-supervised-learning

Is there an approach for the following problem:

Lets say, I trained a neural network on a big dataset for categorizing different fruits in $k$ classes. Afterwards I got a nice model, which performs very well.

Now I want to use the model for categorizing fruits in the corresponding $k$ classes, as it was planned beforehand. Unfortunately the fruits I want to categorize now are all not ripe yet, but my training set consisted only of ripe fruits. Furthermore I have some pictures of these not ripe fruits, but no labels.

How can I adapt my neural network to these slightly different domain with my pictures of not ripe fruits (and no labels!). Performance on the old task does not matter. The only thing I want, is categorizing not ripe fruits.

My only Idea now is to use virtual adversarial training [(VAT)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03976) for the unlabeled pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those are one of the most cited papers:

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7495.pdf
- http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume17/15-239/15-239.pdf
- [http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/paper/Tzeng_Adversarial_Discriminative_Domain_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Tzeng_Adversarial_Discriminative_Domain_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf)
- http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Bousmalis_Unsupervised_Pixel-Level_Domain_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much. There seem to be some very promising ideas for my problem. Take my upvote ;)

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, these papers looks really exciting... I'll try this techniques soon, we could exchange our impressions and considerations :)

Comment: I will definitely report back^^